# Default Options for Prop in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a simple button component using VueJS.  On that button, I have a `size` prop, that I want to be able to take one of five options:

- xsmall
- smalll
- medium
- large
- xlarge

I want to be able to set a couple of classes based on which value is selected.  So, if I select `xsmall`, then the classes `px-3 py-1` will be added.  If I select `small`, then the classes `px-4, px-2` will be added, and so on.

Now, I found a way to get this to work, but I am wondering if there is any easier/better way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
// template
 <button :class="[
  size === 'xsmall' ? xsmall : '',
  size === 'small' ? small : '',
  size === 'medium' ? medium : '',
  size === 'large' ? large : '',
  size === 'xlarge' ? xlarge : ''
 ]">Click Me</button>

// props
size: {
  type: String,
  default: "medium"
}

// data
  xsmall: "px-3 py-1",
  small: "px-4 py-2",
  medium: "px-6 py-3",
  large: "px-8 py-3",
  xlarge: "px-10 py-4",
```

My issue has to do with all those `size === 'xsmall`...` ternary expressions.  Seems to me not so DRY and not so elegant.  Is there a more succinct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make this a mixin:

```
@Component
class SizeMixin extends Vue {
    @Prop({default: "medium"}) readonly size!: Sizes;

    medium: string = "px-6 py-3";
    //...Sizes;
    get classList(){
       return this[this.size] || "";
    }
}
```

So **yes you can use computed** to return specific data value instead of evaluating in template.

Above I used class style component syntax

the usage would be

```
<template>
  <div :class="classList"></div>
</template>

@Component
class CustomComponent extends Mixins(SizeMixin){

  // override medium value
  medium = "px-3 py-3"
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to map it:

```
// template
<button :class="sizemap[size]">Click Me</button>

data: function() {
  return {
    sizemap: {
      xsmall: "px-3 py-1",
      small: "px-4 py-2",
      medium: "px-6 py-3",
      large: "px-8 py-3",
      xlarge: "px-10 py-4"
    }
  }
}
```